# Feeds Module Does not import float numbers

Tags: 7, feeds, importing-exporting

I have used the Drupal feeds module a couple of times so far and without any problem. The last couple of days I have been trying to import a csv with float numbers and it will not work. I have tried to use decimal numbers and it still did not import them. When i change the fields to text it works. With the tamper module i have tried and set it to "format to number" but no luck. Here is what the csv looks like:

```
  guid;Delivery;Price;INDEX
  1;02.01.2010;5.040;5;13,243
  2;03.01.2010;5.040;5;13,243
```

The seperator is ;
The integers and the Price Decimal import fine but the index is empty. No Error message.

If anyone could help me I would appreciate it ;)

regards

wolfmarter

Comment: If the price decimal works, can't you re-format your index double to be with a decimal point rather than a decimal comma? Just since you already know the decimal point works with the feeds importer...

Comment: the problem is that the decimal point is thousand and the decimal comma is the decimal.